# Which Java OAuth library fully implements 1.0 protocol (not it's draft) and is fully configurable?

Tags: oauth, java

everyone.
I've googled a lot but I didnt't find the good library enough. I need one, which will help me to authorize via URL query or via Authorization header params (I want to decide my self which one to use) . I'm in really hurry and I don't want to re-invent a wheel, but I'm about to do this, if I wont find good library enough.

I need it for my desktop application.

So, which Java library could you offer me?

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/ in my own programs. It's very easy to use but still allows you control over the scenario. You just use this library to get the request token and access tokens and handle all the signing and validations. The rest you can easily handle yourself.

And it supports /uRL query or via Authorization header params.